# Android: Add button in a View

Tags: android, button, view, viewgroup

Am doing a Titanium Module (Just Android code), and I need to present a button in a View, so there is no Activity and no xml layout.
I have the following code to add the button in my view:

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup {
 public MyView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  ...
  Button b=new Button(context);
  b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
  b.setText("Some Text");
  this.addView(b);
 }
}
```

Searching in StackOverflow, this code should work... But the button is never shown.
How can I add a button to a View or ViewGroup?

EDIT add onLayout() method:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
     LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(_context);
     l1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
     l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     Button b1=new Button(_context);
     b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
     b1.setText("Button");
     l1.addView(b1);

     this.addView(l1);
}
```

Thanks for your help.-

Comment: If you extend `ViewGroup` you have to implement the `onLayout` method which is abstract to actually position the children on the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Do you mind posting the `onLayout` method? Also, does your views has some sizes set on it?

Comment: @Luksprog onLayout method added to the question. The size of my View is the display width and hight.

Comment: In the `onLayout`  method you have to layout the children by calling the layout method on them with the desired coordinates and not to add views again. If you still want to extend ViewGroup here is a tutorial which has a good explanation on building custom views from ViewGroup http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=1

Answer (score 0):

`ViewGroup` is abstract class. And I think you implemented some of its methods wrong. Try to use any concrete layout, e.g. `LinearLayout`, instead.

Comment: I just extends ViewGroup to add views to MyView. Anyway, am using a Linear Layout to present the view. I had added my onLayout method to my question. Thanks for helping!